# The import org.springframework.data cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I have a strange issue. I've created a class RegisteredUrl:

```
package com.deshand.model;

import java.net.URL;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document

public class RegisteredUrl {

private final String id;
private final URL url;

public RegisteredUrl(String id, URL url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public URL getUrl() {
    return url;
}

}
```

when I got error "The import org.springframework.data cannot be resolved".

My next step: add a maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now "import" error disappeared, but I got 38 more errors and eclipse tells me that I'm trying to override managed version of org.springframework.data.

Complete pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.deshand.adc</groupId>
<artifactId>test-assignment</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? It seems you are trying to override parent dependency with child.

Comment: you must be getting the spring-data-mongodb from some other dependency..

Comment: Try 
`<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <properties>
  <org.springframework.data>1.7.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data>
    </properties>
</parent>`
 by replacing current `<parent>` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

include following in pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error message "the import org.springframework.data.annotation.id cannot be resolved" it means that the spring-data-commons library is not available in your project's classpath.

To fix this issue, you need to make sure that the spring-data-commons library is included in your project's dependencies. If you're using Maven or Gradle, you can add the following dependency to your pom.xml or build.gradle file:
Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
   <version>{spring-data-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:{spring-data-version}'
```

Replace {spring-data-version} with the version of Spring Data that you're using in your project.

After adding the spring-data-commons dependency, rebuild your project and try importing org.springframework.data.annotation.Id again. The error should be resolved.