# java configuration of mongodb with latest spring/spring boot release version

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, spring-framework-beans

I want to create a MongoTemplate bean using spring boot 2.3.4.RELEASE. Earlier I configured it using 2.0.5.RELEASE as below.

```
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {

        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/test"));
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        System.out.println("check");
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
```

I upgraded the spring boot version to 2.3.4.RELEASE. Since, SimpleMongoDbFactory has been deprecated since 2.0.0, I am unable us this configuration. I tried to implement in following way for newer version,

```
public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory() {

        //return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/MGXPI413"));
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

I do not want to downgrade the version. I searched a lot about it, but could not get correct configuration. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/46117153/175554 ?